# VBA Excel Macro that can append data from one row to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro that does the following:

- Checks to see if consecutive rows have the same data (Columns F and G)

I need this macro to also somehow do the following:

- If the data in Columns F and G are identical to the next row
- Combine the data in Columns A,B,C,D,I, and J for both rows to the END of the first row.    As if you had hit ALT + ENTER and entered the data

Any ideas?

```
Sub test()
 'define variables
  Dim RowNum as long, LastRow As long

 'turn off screen updating
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'start below titles and make full selection of data
  RowNum = 2
  LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  Range("A2", Cells(LastRow, 10)).Select

'For loop for all rows in selection with cells
 For Each Row In Selection
 With Cells

 'if first name matches
   If Cells(RowNum, 5) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 5) Then
    'and if last name matches
     If Cells(RowNum, 6) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 6) Then
        *******This is the part I cannot figure out!*******
        Rows(RowNum + 1).EntireRow.Delete
     End If
   End If
 End With

 'increase rownum for next test
  RowNum = RowNum + 1
  Next Row

 'turn on screen updating
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For appending the content of the cell *Alt+Enter* style use following code:

`Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = Cells(RowNum, 1).Value & Chr(10) & Cells(RowNum + 1, 1).Value`

That will work for cells in `A` column.

Comment: So I would need to use this argument separately for each column?

Comment: Yes. If some columns are adjacent, you can cycle through them with `for`, of course